# Bug nas notificações de caixa de entrada

Tags: bug, status-aceito

A alguns dias (acho que mais de uma semana), venho notando um bug nas notificações da caixa de entrada. Não é nada fatal, ou crucial, apenas um bug chato.

Quando eu recebo uma notificação, de comentário ou resposta, sempre conta essa notificação e a última que eu já li, ou seja sempre aparece `2` nas notificações, mas na verdade é apenas uma, a outra é antiga (já lida).

Alguém mais está com esse bug?

Comment: Unico problema que continuo tendo é de vez em quando não conseguir acessar o site e ter que olhar a versão offline.

Comment: Isso só aconteceu comigo sábado. Mas o problema que estou relatando aqui já tem vários dias (acho que antes da migração). Fiquei esperando pra ver se iriam corrigir, mas até agora nada. Por isso estou postando.

Comment: Provavelmente é culpa disto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4225/101

Comment: Não percebi este erro, embora tenha sofrido muito com este outro erro mencionado no link que @bigown compartilhou.

Comment: Não deu pra descobrir ainda. Você poderia colocar um screenshot da sua caixa de entrada da próxima vez que acontecer?

Comment: Ok @Gabe, notei que nas notificações do meta não acontece.